# As I leave this shortcode with the current post id?

Tags: wordpress

This `shortcode` has to be called by specifying an id, as such: `[full_dolar id='25000']` with a single post id. This works for any page I put it on.

I want to remove the id argument from the `shortcode` so all I have to use is`[full_dolar]`.

Below is the code I have currently that requires the id argument.

```
function post_id_shortcode_func($atts) {
            extract(shortcode_atts( array(
                'id' => ''
            ), $atts ) );

            if ((int) $id) {
                // start output
                ob_start();
                $out = '<div class="dolar-shortcode clearfix">';
                dolar_get_full_cambio($id);
                $out .= ob_get_contents();
                $out .= '</div>';
                ob_end_clean();

                return $out;
            }
        }

        // add shortcode for full dolar [full_dolar]
        add_shortcode('full_dolar', 'post_id_shortcode_func');
```

Comment: Did you try `get_post() -> ID`?

Comment: Please make the function for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested and I haven't used Wordpress in some time, but this might work:

```
function post_id_shortcode_func($atts) {
            $id = get_the_ID();

            if ((int) $id) {
                // start output
                ob_start();
                $out = '<div class="dolar-shortcode clearfix">';
                dolar_get_full_cambio($id);
                $out .= ob_get_contents();
                $out .= '</div>';
                ob_end_clean();

                return $out;
            }
        }

// add shortcode for full dolar [full_dolar]
add_shortcode('full_dolar', 'post_id_shortcode_func');
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/